# How many referees are required on a resume/CV?

Tags: application, citations, cv

I have looked at a number of academic resumes to get a feeling for what people expect. I see that the number of referees that people give at the bottom of their resume varies quite a bit.

My question is whether it is essentially always better to provide more referees or whether one should rather stick to a maximum of say 4 ?

Comment: I would not include any names in the CV itself; only the sentence "References are available on request."  If you do decide to list your references, the last sentence on your CV should be "_Additional_ references are available on request."

Comment: @JeffE thanks a lot for your comment ! What would be your rationale not to include them on the CV ?

Comment: If you're sending your CV as part of a job application _that asks for names in advance_ and your references  have agreed to write letters _for that application_, then I think it's okay to include them _in the copy you apply with_.  But if you're just maintaining an up-to-date CV on your web page, leave them off.

Comment: For whom? A student, a faculty member or someone looking for an academic position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are creating your `CV` for some `application` (job or graduate studies). I understand that having three to four good referees is good enough. You need not provide more than that. I am particularly speaking about the academia in US and I  believe it would be different elsewhere (e.g. UK).

Of course you may put different referees according to the requirement. I mean you may need to create different `CVs` for different occasions. Some referees would be better able to acknowledge your work for a given situation. For example you may need to take a `recommendation letter` from a (for example) Mathematics teacher when applying for `graduate studies` in Math.

In fact I have also seen that many people do not put the references. In an application process, they are required to separately provide the names and contacts of the referees.

Answer (score 0):

For entry level professorships I have had requests for between 2 (second tier school with no established research groups) and 5 (first class research group at a R1 in a desirable climate), with 3 being by far the most common. Adds requesting high numbers are often seeking stars and will often state that they will consider tenured placement for qualified applicants.